# Como subir una imagen por defecto en mysql con php

Tags: php, html, mysql, login

Tengo un login en donde tiene un input "file", lo que quiero que haga es, que si el usuario no quiere ingresar una imagen para su perfil, me guarde una imagen por defecto, se que el input "file" no tiene valor por defecto, pero como puedo hacer para poder poner una imagen por defecto si no se carga ninguna imagen de perfil?

```
$imagen = "";

    if($_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'] != null){
        $imagen = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name']));
    }
```

este código lo que hace es guardar en la variable $imagen el archivo que se subio, y si no se sube ninguno no se guarda nada.

Comment: Es basado en opiniones, pero te diré que las imágenes no se deben guardar en la base de datos. En tu proyecto habrá un directorio donde se guardan las imágenes que los usuarios van subiendo e inicialmente tienes una que se llamará `default.jpg` (por ejemplo). Si el usuario no carga ninguna imagen, entonces en el campo de la BD que le corresponde la imagen del usuario, le pones `default.jpg`. Otra opción es una tabla histórica de imágenes, y si el usuario actual no jala ninguna, entonces le asignas `default.jpg`, en una variable de sesión (por ejemplo).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías agregar una condición `else` y en la condición asignarle la ruta de tu imagen predeterminada, así:

```
$imagen = "";
$imagen_default = "ejemplo/default.jpg";

if($_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'] != null){
    $imagen = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name']));
} else {
    $imagen = addslashes(file_get_contents($imagen_default));
}
```